# avoid duplicate data when multiple left join

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

This is my sql select statement http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/353e82/1,
This is the output [image: Output]
I use left join but the data will duplicate on output.
What I want is the data wont duplicate and only show once 
**Earnings**

- Total OT Pay - amount
- Transport - amount
- Uniform - amount

**Deduction**

- Loan - amount
- Unpaid Leave - amount

Thanks

Comment: You should include your actual query in the problem here, not just in a Fiddle link.  Off the top of my head, the `DISTINCT` keyword might work for you.

Comment: I thought put in Fiddle link is more easy to see

Comment: Fiddle is perhaps the _last_ thing you should include.  Show us the query in plain text and maybe some text tables with sample data.

Comment: here data is not duplicate each row seems unique, let us know on which field basis you want to keep your data unique...

Comment: Use **Group by** for avoid duplicate data

Comment: @ZafarMalik Hi, I want show 
Total OT Pay - amount,
Transport - amount,
Uniform - amount,
Loan - amount,
Unpaid Leave - amount,
you can see my output, i dont want be like that

Comment: @Rahautos Hi, i have try to use **GROUP BY** but **Earnings** and **Deduction** still display the data like the picture as i attached.
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/353e82/41

Comment: Here can be multiple combinations suppose you want to get single row instead of current 6 rows means unique data based on payslip_no if yes the do group by on this field...but if you need 3 rows as there are 3 item_remarks for same payslip_no then you have to group by based on either payslip_no,item_remarks or may be some other columns also based on your requirement but without deduction_remarks as it is further distinquishing your data in 6 rows.

Answer (score 0):

If you want single row based on payslip_no then use below query-

```
SELECT
     hrms_salary_payment.`payslip_no` AS payslip_no,
     hrms_salary_payment.`payment_month` AS payment_month,
     hrms_salary_payment.`basic_salary` AS basic_salary,
     hrms_salary_payment.`hours_worken_week` AS hours_worken_week,
     hrms_salary_payment.`ot_hours_worked` AS ot_hours_worked,
     hrms_salary_payment.`total_ot_pay` AS total_ot_pay,
     hrms_salary_payment.`employee_cpf` AS employee_cpf,
     hrms_salary_payment.`employer_cpf` AS employer_cpf,
     hrms_salary_payment.`sdl_payable` AS sdl_payable,
     hrms_salary_payment.`net_salary` AS net_salary,
     hrms_salary_payment.`payment_amount` AS payment_amount,
     hrms_salary_payment.`payment_date` AS payment_date,
     hrms_salary_additional.`item_remark` AS income,
     hrms_salary_additional.`item_amount` AS income_amount,
     hrms_salary_additional.`isCPF` AS isCPF,
     hrms_salary_deduction.`deduction_remark` AS deduction_remark,
     hrms_salary_deduction.`deduction_amount` AS deduction_amount
     FROM `hrms_salary_payment` 
     LEFT JOIN `hrms_salary_additional` ON hrms_salary_additional.payment_id = hrms_salary_payment.payment_id
     LEFT JOIN `hrms_salary_deduction` ON hrms_salary_deduction.payment_id = hrms_salary_payment.payment_id
     where hrms_salary_payment.`payment_id` = 27 
     GROUP BY hrms_salary_payment.`payslip_no`;
```

But if you want 3 rows further distinquished by item_remarks then use below query-

```
SELECT
     hrms_salary_payment.`payslip_no` AS payslip_no,
     hrms_salary_payment.`payment_month` AS payment_month,
     hrms_salary_payment.`basic_salary` AS basic_salary,
     hrms_salary_payment.`hours_worken_week` AS hours_worken_week,
     hrms_salary_payment.`ot_hours_worked` AS ot_hours_worked,
     hrms_salary_payment.`total_ot_pay` AS total_ot_pay,
     hrms_salary_payment.`employee_cpf` AS employee_cpf,
     hrms_salary_payment.`employer_cpf` AS employer_cpf,
     hrms_salary_payment.`sdl_payable` AS sdl_payable,
     hrms_salary_payment.`net_salary` AS net_salary,
     hrms_salary_payment.`payment_amount` AS payment_amount,
     hrms_salary_payment.`payment_date` AS payment_date,
     hrms_salary_additional.`item_remark` AS income,
     hrms_salary_additional.`item_amount` AS income_amount,
     hrms_salary_additional.`isCPF` AS isCPF,
     hrms_salary_deduction.`deduction_remark` AS deduction_remark,
     hrms_salary_deduction.`deduction_amount` AS deduction_amount
     FROM `hrms_salary_payment` 
     LEFT JOIN `hrms_salary_additional` ON hrms_salary_additional.payment_id = hrms_salary_payment.payment_id
     LEFT JOIN `hrms_salary_deduction` ON hrms_salary_deduction.payment_id = hrms_salary_payment.payment_id
     where hrms_salary_payment.`payment_id` = 27 
     GROUP BY hrms_salary_payment.`payslip_no`, hrms_salary_additional.`item_remark`;
```

Comment: You may add multiple fields in group by clause on which basis you want to  do your data distinguish...

Comment: yes, if you want all details then your query is fine and why you are saying it duplicate....